# Check/Uncheck grouped rows in Janus GridEX

Tags: janus, gridex

I use `Janus.Windows.GridEX.GridEX` grid and also have a column which is `ActAsSelector`.

When the rows are grouped in a group, I want to be able to check/uncheck all of them. Do you know build-in functionality or easy way to achieve the goal?

Answer (score 2):

Just set the UseHeaderSelector property of the selector column to True.

[image: Janus Grid Select All Rows]

Answer (score 1):

Janus's GridEx has a built-in functionality for the selector column.

While adding a new column in the GridEx's properties window, select the `Selector` option:

[image: Selector Option]